# clickGraph on AmChart not working

Tags: amcharts

In my exmaple I am trying to take a user to report page, when user clicks on SerialChart Graph.

```
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv",
  {
    "type": "serial",
    ...
    "clickGraph":function(e) {
        alert(1);
    }
```

});

The above does not work and the event is never triggered. I looked into the documentation a few times, cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass event listeners as property. (as far as i know)
What you can do, is adding the listener after the chart is created.

```
chart.addListener("clickGraph", graphClicked);

function graphClicked(e) {
    alert(e.graph.title);
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pnkhfa9d/1/)

Comment: The reason i used it this way is that the clickSlice for PieChart worked. So I assumed should work for all events. I will try your suggestion.